# how to edit method annotation attributes on runtime in springboot project?

Tags: java, reflection, handlerinterceptor

How to edit the method annotation attributes on runtime in springboot project?
I've known there's a way to edit by using reflection like `invocationHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");` but in the newer springboot environment it doesn't work, cause the `invocationHandler` that I got is not the instance of `AnnotationInvocationHandler` but the instance of `SynthesizedMergedAnnotationInvocationHandler`. In `SynthesizedMergedAnnotationInvocationHandler` I can't find the method that let me change the value of the annotation fields on the fly.

I'm trying to reused the way that worked in old version just like：

```
InvocationHandler invocationHandler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(rateLimit);
Field field = invocationHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
field.setAccessible(true);
Map params = (Map)field.get(invocationHandler);
params.put("fields1",xxx);
```

but there's no fields called `memberValues`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I won't use this method anymore, seems like spring dont want annotation fields value been modified at the runtime. i use spring environment to parse dynamic placeholder to solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).